# Move .war from Jenkins to wildfly

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, wildfly

I'm having trouble moving the .war geard by Jenkins to Widfly, both are in my Docker.

```
[INFO] Building war: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/argentum-web/target/argentum-web.war
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.717 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-28T00:55:49Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[argentum-web] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins541409688598903433.sh
+ cd /opt/jboss/wildfly
/tmp/jenkins541409688598903433.sh: 2: cd: can't cd to /opt/jboss/wildfly
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Build -> Execute Shell

```
cp /var/jenkins_home/workspace/argentum-web/target/argentum-web.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/argentum-web.war
```

docker-compose:

version: '2'

```
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    volumes:
    - /home/rafaelvicio/Dev/jenkins_example/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    - 50000:50000
  wildfly:
    image: jboss/wildfly
    volumes:
    - /home/rafaelvicio/Dev/jenkins_example/wildfly/:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
    ports:
    - 8180:8080
    - 9990:9990
```

Answer (score 0):

Your copy statement is incorrect. Remember that your jenkins job is running in its own container. And your Jboss container is different.

If you're running the below command in the Jenkins container

```
cp /var/jenkins_home/workspace/argentum-web/target/argentum-web.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/argentum-web.war
```

It (jenkins) does not know where `/opt/jboss/wildfly` is. Since that path does not exist in Jenkins container.

The copy command should instead be

```
cp /home/rafaelvicio/Dev/jenkins_example/jenkins/<path-to-war-file> /home/rafaelvicio/Dev/jenkins_example/wildfly/<path-to-deployment-folder>
```

Comment: cp: cannot stat '/home/rafaelvicio/Dev/jenkins_example/jenkins/argentum-web/target/argentum-web.war': No such file or directory
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure